# discover a latent (confounding) effect in a model

Tags: multivariate-analysis, confounding

Lets say I want to model the relationship between `sales` and 3 predictors: marketing, competition and visits (`mkt`, `comp` and `visits`).

Here are the simulation parameters:

```
b1 <- 0.3
b2 <- -0.9
b3 <- 0.5
b4 <- 0.6

comp <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
mkt <- b4*comp + rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
visits <- b3*mkt + rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
sales <- b1*visits + b2*comp + rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
```

lets say we are interested in how marketing affects sales. From the equations, we know that `sales ~ b1*b3*mkt`. However:

```
DF <- data_frame(sales, visits, mkt, comp)
ggplot(DF, aes(mkt, sales)) + geom_point(size = 3)
```

It looks like marketing is *negatively* correlated to sales, which is of course non-sense (although the relationship is not significant).

```
model1 <- lm(sales ~ ., data = DF)
summary(model1)
```

How can we "discover" the true effect of marketing on sales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Visits" is a [bad control](http://www.g-feed.com/2012/10/bad-control.html).  It's an intermediate outcome.  Controlling for intermediate outcomes changes the interpretation of the coef on the variable of interest to reflect the effect of `mkt` which does not flow through `visits`.  In your simulation, this is nothing but noise.

Just take it out, in your simple example.  If however you lots of things contribute to visits besides marketing, your case gets trickier.

However, I suspect that you might have an endogeneity problem as well.  Marketing might drive up sales, but sales might drive down marketing.